# CSS fixed div top to parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to have the div to always fix floating top appear within a div and my code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<p>Some on page content</p>
<div id="cover">
    <div id="floatdiv">floating fix top bar</div>
    <p>first contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p>
</div>
<p>Other content ..</p>
```

CSS:

```
#cover{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#floatdiv{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csLd6j7n/

How can it be done?

Comment: @Shikkediel It would be better if you could show it with example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `position: absolute` to remain the div. Then use `width: inherit` to get the parent's width, also specify the `padding` to `top` and `bottom` to avoid the overflowing of `div`

```
#floatdiv{
     background-color:black;
     color:white;
     padding-top:10px;
     padding-bottom:10px;
     position: absolute;
     width: inherit; 
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/po1wv5zq/4/)**

**UPDATE:**

added `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to display the first value

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/po1wv5zq/6/)**

Comment: with this css the first value is not visible although the top header is fixed.

Comment: yeah I didn't notice that the first value was hidden, maybe adding two break lines (`<br/>`) below the *top bar* will do but I don't think it's a good idea..  http://jsfiddle.net/5htwaLhg/1/

Answer (score 4):

I have done it with following html and css, Hope it helps.

HTML

```
     <p>Some on page content</p>
      <div id="cover" class="cover">
        <div id="floatdiv">floating fix top bar</div>
        <div class="scrollableContent">
          <p>first contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p>
        </div>
     </div>
    <p>Other content ..</p>
```

CSS

```
#cover{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#floatdiv{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}
.scrollableContent{
     height: 250px;
    margin-top:30px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Working with first option visible](http://jsfiddle.net/csLd6j7n/5/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can give it a `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` :

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csLd6j7n/1/)

```
#floatdiv {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @dwreck08 Make a simple addition to your answer so that I am able to remove the downvote.

Comment: I cannot remove my downvote unless you edit your answer in some way.

Comment: Instead of `width: 100%` use `width: inherit`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set left/top properties, it will be `fixed`/`absolute` against the closest `relative`/`absolute` parent div.

```
#floatdiv {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    //I would go with absolute
    position: absolute;
    width: 465px;
    display: block;
}
```

If you use fixed instead absolute, when you scroll the page, the fixed div will be also visible. Also, add `padding-top: 45px` to `#cover` or the first paragraph will be hidden behind `#floatdiv`

Answer (score 0):

A little Bit Modified Your existing Code

```
<p>Some on page content</p>
<div class="outerCovering">
<div id="cover">
    <div id="floatdiv">floating fix top bar</div>
    <div><p>first contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p> <p>contents</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is your Css code

```
#cover{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#floatdiv{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Reference Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csLd6j7n/4/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML page:

```
<p>some content page</p>
   <div class="outerCovering">
 <div id="cover">
  <div id="floatdiv">floating fix top bar</div>
  <div><p>first contents</p> <p>second contents</p> <p>third contents</p></div>               
 </div>
 </div>
```

css page:

```
 #cover{
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: auto;

 #floatdiv{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 position: absolute;`enter code here`
 width: inherit; 
 }
  `
```